# C# Combobox - item list using ODBC database

Tags: c#, combobox, odbc, pervasive

How can I in C# get item list in combobox using as datasource database table connected by ODBC?? It's Pervasive database.

Comment: Gave you tried via Databinding a list to the Combobox (Itemssource) you retrieved from the database?
Maybe check MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the two properties of the combobox:

- [`ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx).
- [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx).

To bind the items of the combo box to the data returned by odbc. And set the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f.aspx) of the combo box to the list of items returned by the ODBC:

```
 comboboxName.DataSource = dataSetComingFromODBC;
 comboboxName.ValueMember = "Id";
 comboboxName.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

For how to connect to pervasive database, there is an article in their documenation on how to do so

- [**Connecting to a Pervasive Database**](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/adonet/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=netquik.01.4.html&single=true)